# How to use AVG() with 2 parameter in one view

Tags: php, sql

I have a table view like this

```
CREATE VIEW detail_sp AS (

  SELECT ds.spesific_goal,k.pertanyaan,su.sub_unit,ds.skor FROM
    detail_survey ds
  LEFT JOIN 
    kuesioner k 
  ON
    ds.nomor_soal=k.id
  LEFT JOIN
    sub_unit su
  ON 
    k.id_subunit=su.id
);
```

The structure from the code like this,

spesific_goal | pertanyaan| sub_unit | skor

The sample data output is

```
mysql> select * from detail_sp where spesific_goal = 1
    -> ;
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------+----------+------+
| spesific_goal | pertanyaan
                      | sub_unit | skor |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------+----------+------+
|             1 | Dilakukan survei kepuasan pelanggan
                      | Niaga    |    4 |
|             1 | Terdapat perjanjian pelayanan (Service Agreement) sebelum meng
gunakan jasa dari PLN | Niaga    |    4 |
|             1 | Dilakukan survei kepuasan pelanggan
                      | Niaga    |    4 |
|             1 | Terdapat perjanjian pelayanan (Service Agreement) sebelum meng
gunakan jasa dari PLN | Niaga    |    4 |
|             1 | Dilakukan survei kepuasan pelanggan
                      | Niaga    |    4 |
|             1 | Terdapat perjanjian pelayanan (Service Agreement) sebelum meng
gunakan jasa dari PLN | Niaga    |    4 |
|             1 | Dilakukan survei kepuasan pelanggan
                      | Niaga    |    3 |
|             1 | Terdapat perjanjian pelayanan (Service Agreement) sebelum meng
gunakan jasa dari PLN | Niaga    |    4 |
|             1 | Dilakukan survei kepuasan pelanggan
                      | Niaga    |    3 |
|             1 | Terdapat perjanjian pelayanan (Service Agreement) sebelum meng
gunakan jasa dari PLN | Niaga    |    4 |
|             1 | Dilakukan survei kepuasan pelanggan
                      | Niaga    |    4 |
|             1 | Terdapat perjanjian pelayanan (Service Agreement) sebelum meng
gunakan jasa dari PLN | Niaga    |    4 |
|             1 | Dilakukan survei kepuasan pelanggan
                      | Niaga    |    2 |
|             1 | Terdapat perjanjian pelayanan (Service Agreement) sebelum meng
gunakan jasa dari PLN | Niaga    |    4 |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------+----------+------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

how to calculate `skor` with `pertanyaan` and `sub-units` into parameters ?

So the average score calculation is obtained when the questions and sub units are the same.

if i use avg i hope the result like this

```
mysql> select * from detail_sp where spesific_goal = 1
    -> ;
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------+----------+------+
| spesific_goal | pertanyaan
                      | sub_unit | skor |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------+----------+------+
|             1 | Dilakukan survei kepuasan pelanggan
                      | Niaga    |    4 |
|             1 | Terdapat perjanjian pelayanan (Service Agreement) sebelum meng
gunakan jasa dari PLN | Niaga    |    4 |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------+----------+------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The skor is get from avg.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Kindly add sample data and desired output.

Comment: @zarruq the sample is added. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `avg` function along with `group by` as below.

```
SELECT ds.spesific_goal,
       k.pertanyaan,
       su.sub_unit,
       avg(ds.skor)
FROM detail_survey ds
LEFT JOIN kuesioner k ON ds.nomor_soal=k.id
LEFT JOIN sub_unit su ON k.id_subunit=su.id
GROUP BY ds.spesific_goal,
         k.pertanyaan,
         su.sub_unit;
```